# Use navigation path from menu for permalink

Tags: menus, permalinks, navigation

I now switched to permalinks and defined my own structure 
`/%postname%`. If I click on a menu item it takes the path from the parent page (hierarchy defined directly when editing a page).

What I want is for the permalink to use the structure of the menu.

How can this be done?

Comment: What do you mean by 'takes the path from the parent page' - do you mean that the permalink of pages reflects its hierarchy: e.g. if page2A was a child of page1, it has permalink `www.example.com/page1/page2a`?

Comment: @StephenHarris: Yes, I mean that! This is the current situation and I want to change this behavior. The hierarchy of the menu should be chosen not the one of your example.

Comment: Why can't you set the parents according to the menu structure? (Or more usually, have the menu reflect the parent-child relationship). Why is there a difference between the page and menu relationships?

Comment: Yes, I could set the menu structure, but I don't know if the user would make this, when he creates a new page. The difference is here because I needed the hierarchy for some special adaptions I made (read the content from certain sub pages and so on ...). Normally, the menu should define the structure of the permalink. Thats the reason why I asked for it. And the menu hierarchy is already available. So one would have to define the hierarchy two times. Perhaps I don't understand a certain concept ...

Comment: WP has a lot of complexities to account for in its URLs. I've been thinking about this exact same thing but there are many edge cases like feeds, single posts, comment pages, custom rewrite endpoints etc... Total nightmare

Comment: If you can some how pass variables on links contained ONLY within the menu link structure and output, you could then use those variables to conditionally control your rewrite rules as you'd be able to determine whether a click/request for a URL is coming from a menu item or coming from somewhere else in your theme other than a menu and thus present a URL structure based upon that origin. Seems possible to me... Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

> Yes, I could set the menu structure, but I don't know if the user would make this, when he creates a new page. The difference is here because I needed the hierarchy for some special adaptions I made (read the content from certain sub pages and so on ...). Normally, the menu should define the structure of the permalink. That's the reason why I asked for it. And the menu hierarchy is already available. So one would have to define the hierarchy two times. Perhaps I don't understand a certain concept.

The "menu" doesn't define anything in any web application. At least not if the architecture isn't bogus and assumes that everyone actually got a menu. There're other navigation ideas as well.

To get data from the siblings of a page, you can use [`get_page_children()`](http://queryposts.com/function/get_page_children/) - detailed [use case in Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_page_children). That function will work for hierarchical post types as well.

Answer (score 0):

**THE PERMALINKS**

The permalinks in WordPress are generated by `WP_Rewrite` class in `wp-includes/rewrite.php`. It translates the URL being entered into the browser into query variables which are then used by `WP_Query` to determine which content will be loaded.

There are rewrite rules which define the structure of permalinks.

Categories are structured by default as `website/category/category_name`
Pages are structured as `website/pagename`

For posts, it is `website/custom_structure`, where `custom_structure` is what you define on the **Settings > Permalink** on admin page.

Pages, by default, reflect their parents. So third level page will have: `website/Level1/Level2/Level3`

**THE NAVIGATION MENU**

The navigation menu doesn't reflect the permalink, it depends on how user will build the structure of the menu.

So, if you need the menu to follow the page structures, create a menu based on them. Having the permalink structure follow your menu takes more effort than you could imagine.

Having custom permalinks requires these actions:

1. You have to create custom structure for each part of your page which
   are categories, tags, port_formats, taxonomies, posts etc.
2. You have to create rewrite rule for them as well.
3. You have to make sure that they don't conflict each other.

Answer (score 0):

i think you could be using the wp_nav_menu function to display a menu that is defined inside the appearance > menu section.

To do what you want, you'd have to use wp_list_pages to list the pages in the order and hierarchy that they are in on the dashboard:

```
<ul>
<?php wp_list_pages('&title_li=<h2>Pages</h2>' ); ?>
</ul>
```

This will output a menu in an un ordered list that replicates the structure of your **Pages**,  including their child pages etc, indented via an unordered listm complete with the correct permalinks

Comment: Please explain how that could solve the problem. Add a code example. Right now it doesn’t even look like an answer.

Comment: the wp_nav_menu outputs a menu so it visually looks like there is a hierarchy, but the pages in the menu might all exist at the same level (i.e. flat).  If the pages are in a tree like structure (ie parent > child, etc) the wp_list_pages will output html that adheres to the relationship of the pages, including the permalinks:

<ul>
<?php wp_list_pages('&title_li=<h2>Pages</h2>' ); ?>
</ul>

Comment: Please update your answer, do not hide essential information in a comment.

Comment: answer updated :)